# Writing Tests for Core Data Exist Feature

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to write a test for my Budget Core Data class to make sure that two budgets with the same name cannot be added. Here is my Budget class.

```
@objc(Budget)
class Budget: Model {
    
    override func save() throws {
        
        if try exists(name ?? "") {
            throw BudgetError.duplicateName
        } else {
            try save()
        }
    }
    
    private func exists(_ name: String) throws -> Bool {
        
        let request = Budget.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        
        let budgets = try viewContext.fetch(request)
        return !budgets.isEmpty
    }
    
}
```

The main issue I am facing is that the test is always failing on the first call to the save function.

```
 func test_Throws_Duplicate_Name_Exception() throws {
        
        var thrownError: Error?
        
        let budget = Budget(context: CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext)
        budget.name = "Car Rental"
        
        CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext.refreshAllObjects()
        try budget.save() <-- TEST FAILS HERE AND THROWS duplicateName EXCEPTION
        
        // save it again
        XCTAssertThrowsError(try budget.save()) {
            thrownError = $0
        }
        
        XCTAssertEqual(thrownError as? BudgetError, .duplicateName)
    }
```

I think the main reason is that when a budget object is created as shown below:

```
 let budget = Budget(context: CoreDataProvider.shared.viewContext)
```

The budget is also added to the ViewContext and the exists function returns true and the BudgetError is thrown.

What can I do about this situation? The error should happen when I call save the second time, not the first time.

Comment: You're both adding it to and reading from the `viewContext`, so it makes sense that it would fail. Why are you implementing this functionality yourself instead of just using Core Data's built-in constraint feature?

Comment: What is the Core Data constraint feature? I don't see anything in the Core Data Model Editor?

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/constraints-core-data-entities/

Comment: It's right under where you set your model class in the current version of Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create first, try retrieving it first, then if it exists, you can modify, otherwise create the new one.